# Tangent Bundles to manifolds

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, differential-topology, vector-bundles

I am having trouble trying to visualize exactly what a tangent bundle to the klein bottle is spuposed to look like. Is it possible for one to decompose it as a direct sum of simpler bundles?